# How to get rid of old data and of old graph in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://chartjs.org) to make a graph.

I encounter a problem when I use my graph. The old graph with the old values are not gone when I hover my cursor on the graph. According to the doc, I tried to use .destroy() or .clear() to get rid of the old data, but it doesn't work.

Here is the following codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>hp mp</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="hpmpGraph()">
 <script>
  function hpmpGraph() {
   var hp = document.hpmpForm.HP.value,
    mp = document.hpmpForm.MP.value,
    ctx = document.getElementById('hpmpratio').getContext('2d');
    
   var data = {
    labels: ["HP","MP"],
    datasets: 
     [{
      data: [hp,mp],
      backgroundColor: ["#EF0000","#0000EF"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF0000","#0000FF"]
     }]
   };
   var options = {};

   var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
   });
  }
 </script>

 <h1>HP & MP</h1>
 <form name=hpmpForm method=post>
  HP : <input type="text" name="HP" value="100"><br>
  MP : <input type="text" name="MP" value="100"><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="hpmpGraph();">Click</button>
  <h2>Pie graph</h2>
  <canvas id="hpmpratio" height="50"></canvas>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HP and MP are both set at 100. Try set 1000 for HP. Then put your cursor on the graph and move in circle. Sometime, the old graph will show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not recreate chart since that is not allowed in v2, instead you need to replace the data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>hp mp</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="hpmpGraph()">
 <script>
   var myPieChart = null
        var config = {options:{},type:'pie'}
  function hpmpGraph() {
   var hp = document.hpmpForm.HP.value,
    mp = document.hpmpForm.MP.value,
    ctx = document.getElementById('hpmpratio').getContext('2d');
   
                        config.data = {
    labels: ["HP","MP"],
    datasets: 
     [{
      data: [hp,mp],
      backgroundColor: ["#EF0000","#0000EF"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF0000","#0000FF"]
     }]
   };
   if(myPieChart == null){
                            myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
                        }else{
                            myPieChart.update()
                        }
       
      
  }
 </script>

 <h1>HP & MP</h1>
 <form name=hpmpForm method=post>
  HP : <input type="text" name="HP" value="100"><br>
  MP : <input type="text" name="MP" value="100"><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="hpmpGraph();">Click</button>
  <h2>Pie graph</h2>
  <canvas id="hpmpratio" height="50"></canvas>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>hp mp</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="hpmpGraph()">
 <script>
  function hpmpGraph() {
   var hp = document.hpmpForm.HP.value,
    mp = document.hpmpForm.MP.value,
    ctx = document.getElementById('hpmpratio').getContext('2d');
    
   var data = {
    labels: ["HP","MP"],
    datasets: 
     [{
      data: [hp,mp],
      backgroundColor: ["#EF0000","#0000EF"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF0000","#0000FF"]
     }]
   };
   var options = {};

   var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
   });
  }
 </script>

 <h1>HP & MP</h1>
 <form name=hpmpForm method=post>
  HP : <input type="text" name="HP" value="100"><br>
  MP : <input type="text" name="MP" value="100"><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="hpmpGraph();">Click</button>
  <h2>Pie graph</h2>
  <canvas id="hpmpratio" height="50"></canvas>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that I shouldn't have recreate chart